# How does one add set symbols in manim?

Tags: python, latex, manim

I'm trying to write the set of natural and real numbers in manim using MathTex, but I haven't found a way that works. Every time I try to use shortcuts I've searched up about LaTeX, such as \N, \natnums, \mathbb{N}, and such don't work, returning the error message:

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Here is the troublesome part in the current version of my code:

NtoR=MathTex(r"\natnums","\longrightarrow",r"\reals")
self.play(Write(NtoR,RIGHT*2))

As previously mentioned, I get the following error message:

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

Comment: Can you post your actual code so we can try it out ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the amsfonts package to your manim code:

```py
class WriteNaturalNumber(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        myTemplate = TexTemplate()
        myTemplate.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage{amsfonts}") # adds package to construct
        # Write the symbol
        tex = Tex(
            r"$\mathbb{N}$",
            tex_template=myTemplate,
            font_size=144,
        )
        self.add(tex)
```

Result:

[image: Natural number symbol]